# Does Boost or STL provide a functionlity similar to QString?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, stl

Using QString, one can do the following:

```
QString const sentence = QString("First name: %1, Last name: %2")
                           .arg("John")
                           .arg("Doe"); 

// sentence is now "First name: John, Last name: Doe"
```

Does Boost / STL have something similar? I would like to construct a string similar to this way without using sstream << operator.

Comment: Use case: One typically uses QString this way to construct a SQL query.

Comment: In my use case, I use it to concisely construct my exception message.

Comment: Just watch out for [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) when you're constructing those SQL queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you want [boost.format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/format/doc/format.html)